# CCSprite rotation like Car Steering in Cocos2D

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, rotation, ccsprite

Is there any way to rotate a CCSprite to behave like a car Steering?If i release my touch with the CCSprite,it should automatically return to its original position in a smooth way exactly like a steering!Im using the below code,

```
-(void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {

        UITouch *touch=[touches anyObject];
        //acquire the previous touch location
        CGPoint firstLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:[touch view]];
         location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];


        CGPoint touchingPoint = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];
        CGPoint firstTouchingPoint = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:firstLocation];

        CGPoint firstVector = ccpSub(firstTouchingPoint, Steering.position);
        CGFloat firstRotateAngle = -ccpToAngle(firstVector);
        CGFloat previousTouch = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(firstRotateAngle);

        CGPoint vector = ccpSub(touchingPoint, Steering.position);
        CGFloat rotateAngle = -ccpToAngle(vector);
        CGFloat currentTouch = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(rotateAngle);
        dialrotation+=currentTouch-PreviousTouch;
        sprite.rotation=dialrotation;
        }
```

This rotates my CCSprite Smoothly,but i don't know how  to return back to its original position like Car Steering.Is there any way to do so in Cocos2D?

Answer (score 0):

In `ccTouchesBegan` method store the value of sprite.rotation somewhere, in `ccTouchesEnded` run `CCRotateTo` action on your sprite using this stored value.